# How do I reload my game in Candy Box?

Tags: candy-box

I saved and bookmarked my game, yet when I open the bookmark, it starts a new game... My friends told me to put my password into the URL, but it kept saying URL not found. I can't find any login button and I really don't want to lose all my progress:( I had gotten SO far(100 lollipops per second)! Please help:)

Comment: http://candies.aniwey.net/index.php?pass=YOURPASSWORDHERE

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me. I'm guessing you've got the password wrong - at a guess, you probably chopped  a character off the end without realizing it. There's not much you can do about that, I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 1):

You put this in link bar http://candies.aniwey.net/index.php?pass=xxxxx
You change xxxxx with the password you get when you save.
I'm sure it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip for those that have lost your save using Chrome.
Happened to me today. Chrome crashed before I could save the password.

Go to `C:\Users\#YourUser#\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Open the file "History" and search for `http://candies.aniwey.net/index.php?pass=`

Your password should be one of the results.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's a much simpler GUI solution for this than to read directly from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the original candy box website, look for the FAQ in small print at the bottom, and click it. Then you should copy and paste the URL it has there under the question about saving, replace the xxxxx with your password, and you're done.